# WPF controls in user input form visually corrupted

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have a a desktop application (C# Net 4.5) that contains a number of wpf input forms for user input.  I have recently experienced corruption on the screen with some of the wpf controls as illustrated:

[image: WPF form]

Buttons, comboboxes, radio buttons and checkboxes are all affected (a checkbox disappears when mouse hovers over it - see missing 'Deductible expense' checkbox in illustration)
The result is the same when running from within VisualStudio19 or running the separate .exe application.
Has anyone else experienced this behaviour and can suggest a fix?

Comment: Can we have some code please? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure that code will help as the problem I am experiencing is not experienced by the application on different PCs, just the one.  I assume it is a .NET corruption on this particular application (and not a generic Windows 10 corruption) as it does not affect other applications on the same PC.  My hope was that someone would recognise this behaviour and suggest a source and fix.

Answer (score 2):

I received an answer to this from a Microsoft Q&A:
[Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/630951/wpf-controls-in-user-input-form-visually-corrupted.html)

Disabling a sound driver called Nahimic (through System Configuration to prevent it re-loading after a shutdown) fixed the distortion issue.  Quite why a sound driver should affect visual rendering of the UI is beyond me, but the fix worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing the [Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/630951/wpf-controls-in-user-input-form-visually-corrupted.html).
I did not have Nahimic installed, but I do have Sonic Studio.
Once I shut Sonic Studio down, the WPF distortions seem to have disappeared.